# difference between nested interval theorem and cantor intersection theorem

Tags: real-analysis

What is difference between the nested interval theorem and Cantor intersection theorem? In $\mathbb{R}$, are they the same? When are they different? 
Intuitively, I feel they are same for $\mathbb{R^n}$. But what happens in a general space?

Comment: By "same" do you mean does one follow from the other, or do you mean that they refer to exactly the same property?

Answer (score -1):

> **Nested Interval Theorem**
>   Consider a family of closed and bounded real intervals, $I_1 = [a_1, b_1], I_2 = [a_2, b_2], \ldots$. 
>   If $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1} \leq b_n$ for all $n$ then there is an $x$ which is in every $I_n$, that is, $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n \neq \emptyset$.
>
> **Cantor's Intersection Theorem**
>   Let S be a complete metric space. Consider a decreasing, nested sequence $\{C_k\}$ of nonempty closed and bounded sets in $S$. Then, $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k \neq \emptyset$.

It seems to me that Cantor's Intersection Theorem generalizes the Nested Interval Theorem to arbitrary complete spaces.

To see why the completeness hypothesis is necessary, consider $\{C_k\}={[0,\frac{1}{k}]}$. If $S=\mathbb{R}$, then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k = \{0\}$. If $S=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, then $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} C_k = \emptyset$.

Comment: But it seems to me that a complete metric space would not, in general, have this property for "closed and bounded" sets.

Comment: Can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: Seems you (Henry) are studying metric spaces.  If so then  just look in your text for a discussion of compact metric spaces.  There are interesting examples of  closed and bounded sets in complete metric spaces that are not compact.  The lazy solution is just to find a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ that is equivalent to the usual metric but makes it into a bounded space (relative to the new metric).